# Leading coefficient of polynomial with more than one variable

Tags: polynomials

What is the leading coefficient of a polynomial with more than one variable, when two or more terms have the same degree but different coefficients?

For example:
$3x^2y^2 + 5xy^3$.

The degree is 4.  Is the leading coefficient 3, 5, both, none?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a unique notion of leading coefficient in more than one variable. Which term you decide to be the leading term depends on what you want to do. The keyword here is [monomial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to speak of the leading coefficient, you need to define an order for your monomials.

You can read more on the monomial orders [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order)

How, depending on which order you use, the answer could be either term.