# What is the leading term of a polynomial? (Tangent Cone)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, reference-request

This is likely a duplicate, but I was unable to find a reference, so apologies if it is.

In the case of a polynomial with one variable, say $f=a_nX^n + ... + a_1X + a_0$, I would say the common definition of the **leading term** of $f$ is the term $a_nX^n$. Fixing a monomial ordering we can generalize this definition to multivariate polynomials, as is suggested for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186947/leading-coefficient-of-polynomial-with-more-than-one-variable).

Yet, when reading about *tangent cones* in algebraic geometry, another notion of leading term arises: Any multivariate polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ has a unique decomposition $f = \sum_{k=0}^n f^{(k)}$ into homogeneous polynomials of degree $k=0...n$. The **leading term** of $f$ is the first (minimal $k$) nonzero $f^{(k)}$. This appears for example in *Eisenbud Harris - Geometry of Schemes* (p. 107) or *Görtz Wedhorn - Algebraic Geometry I* (p. 166)

> Does the latter notion have another name? What is a good resource to read about it?

As ideals generated by the latter notion seem to be relevant, I would like to find more information, but the former notion makes searching for it rather difficult.

As always thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Really, the leading term just depends on the ordering you choose. Anyway, the leading term is sometimes also called the *initial term*, as in [this paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/what-is.pdf) by Sturmfels. Searching for "initial ideal" gives lots of results.

Comment: Right, but what is that thing *Eisenbud, Harris, Görtz & Wedhorn* talk about?

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case it's called the *initial form*, as in [this paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/tropical/sec3.pdf). Two other references are Cox, Little, O'Shea's *Using Algebraic Geometry* section 8.5 and Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra...* sections 5.1 and 7.5. There is also the term *local order* but I think it's not quite what you're after, since most authors still usually define this as a monomial order.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful!